# vroidのunityへのインポート

Tags: unity3d

pc     windows10
vroid  v0.5.0
unity  2017.4.15f1
UniVRM 0.50

unityにunivrmをインストールし、
vroidのvrmデータをunityにインストールしました。
[image: 状態]

画像の状態となり
model rig animationのボタンが表示されません。
そうしたら表示できますか。
困っています。

Comment: 「model rig animationのボタン」というのは、FBX などの 3D ファイルをインポートしたときに出てくる ["\[Model\] \[Rig\] \[Animation\] \[Materials\]" のボタンたち](https://docs.unity3d.com/ja/2017.4/Manual/FBXImporter-Rig.html)のことでしょうか？　VRM ファイルをインポートし、このボタンを使って何をなさりたいのかの目標を質問文に追記して頂けると回答がより集まりやすいのかなと思いました。質問文には「編集」から自由に追記できますので、後からでも書き足せます :)

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。
vroidで作ったキャラクターをvrchatにアップロードしたかったのです。
nekketsuuuさんの回答を見てFBXファイルに変換すればいいことに気づき、無事ボタンを表示できました。
ありがとうございます。

Comment: 澤田こう さん、何やら解決したようで良かったです :)　スタック・オーバーフローでは[自己回答](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)ができ、また推奨していますので、是非自分で回答してみてください。しばらく時間が経つとその自己回答の横のチェックマークを押して回答を承認することもできるようになります。